# Wordpress multi sites - different hosts

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have approximately 20 simple Wordpress sites, but each, on a different host company. 
That's  because I wanted the sites to be completely separated (with different ip and all).

My question is:
Is there a paid service (maybe on the cloud?) that give me the ability to manage multiple Wordpress sites that each of them on a different hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://managewp.com/ have a look I think it one of the few that can manage sites on separate servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted separate IP, that's probably for marketing and SEO purposes. In that case you should check out https://www.seosamba.com/ for the free and premium WP plugins. You can optimize any number of WordPress websites from a single interface.

Answer (score 0):

Another one that I've been using is InfiniteWP (http://infinitewp.com/). They even offer a free version if you don't need all the features.
As far as I'm aware, they only offer a self-hosted solution though.